# Is the Hyper modifier key usable on non-X11 platforms?

Tags: key-bindings, osx, microsoft-windows, linux, keyboard

I have a hyper modifier setup, however I was wondering if it's possible to use this on any windowing systems besides X11, for example:

- macOS
- Wayland
- Win32
- The terminal.

Comment: Yes. I use `(setq ns-command-modifier 'hyper)` on Mac to make the Cmd key act as Hyper. Some versions of Emacs for Mac use `mac-command-modifier` instead.